# InternetCheckConnection always return false

Tags: windows, connection, wininet

I want to use the `Wininet` function `InternetCheckConnection` to check whenever the machine is connected to the internet and can access a specific host.
The problem is that this function is always returning **false**, no matter the URL I put on it.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384346(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

**Following combination works for me on Windows 7 and Windows XP SP3:**

```
 InternetCheckConnection("http://www.google.com", FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0) ;
```

GetLastError() returns 0 if the connexion is possible and it returns
12029 (The attempt to connect to the server failed) if not.

**Following combonations don't work for me :**

```
  InternetCheckConnection(NULL, FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0) ;
```

GetLastError() returns 12016 (The requested operation is invalid).

```
  InternetCheckConnection(NULL, 0, 0) ;
  InternetCheckConnection(("http://www.google.com", 0, 0) ;
```

for both GetLastError() returns 2250 (The network connection could not be found).

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked `GetLastError()` ? If I read MSDN correctly, you would need to check for `ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED` to determine whether you're truly offline.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but perhaps this is due to a personal firewall blocking all outgoing connections for one of the Windows DLLs and / or your application?

Comment: I don't have a firewall configured on my machine. All protocols and ports can be accessed freely. :)

Comment: Well, as I said, it was just a wild guess :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft API document **[InternetCheckConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetcheckconnectiona)** is deprecated.

> [InternetCheckConnection is available for use in the operating systems specified in the Requirements section. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions. Instead, use NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile or the NLM Interfaces. ]

Instead of this API we can use **[INetworkListManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nn-netlistmgr-inetworklistmanager)** interface to check whether Internet is connected or not for windows platform.

Here below is the win32 codebase :

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ObjBase.h>      // include the base COM header
    #include <Netlistmgr.h>

    // Instruct linker to link to the required COM libraries
    #pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")

    using namespace std;

    enum class INTERNET_STATUS
    {
        CONNECTED,
        DISCONNECTED,
        CONNECTED_TO_LOCAL,
        CONNECTION_ERROR
    };

    INTERNET_STATUS IsConnectedToInternet();

    int main()
    {
        INTERNET_STATUS connectedStatus = INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTION_ERROR;
        connectedStatus = IsConnectedToInternet();
        switch (connectedStatus)
        {
        case INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTED:
            cout << "Connected to the internet" << endl;
            break;
        case INTERNET_STATUS::DISCONNECTED:
            cout << "Internet is not available" << endl;
            break;
        case INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTED_TO_LOCAL:
            cout << "Connected to the local network." << endl;
            break;
        case INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTION_ERROR:
        default:
            cout << "Unknown error has been occurred." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    INTERNET_STATUS IsConnectedToInternet()
    {
        INTERNET_STATUS connectedStatus = INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTION_ERROR;
        HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;

        try
        {
            hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                INetworkListManager* pNetworkListManager;
                hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_NetworkListManager, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(INetworkListManager), (LPVOID*)&pNetworkListManager);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    NLM_CONNECTIVITY nlmConnectivity = NLM_CONNECTIVITY::NLM_CONNECTIVITY_DISCONNECTED;
                    VARIANT_BOOL isConnected = VARIANT_FALSE;
                    hr = pNetworkListManager->get_IsConnectedToInternet(&isConnected);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        if (isConnected == VARIANT_TRUE)
                            connectedStatus = INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTED;
                        else
                            connectedStatus = INTERNET_STATUS::DISCONNECTED;
                    }

                    if (isConnected == VARIANT_FALSE && SUCCEEDED(pNetworkListManager->GetConnectivity(&nlmConnectivity)))
                    {
                        if (nlmConnectivity & (NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_LOCALNETWORK | NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_SUBNET | NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV6_LOCALNETWORK | NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV6_SUBNET))
                        {
                            connectedStatus = INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTED_TO_LOCAL;
                        }
                    }

                    pNetworkListManager->Release();
                }
            }

            CoUninitialize();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            connectedStatus = INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTION_ERROR;
        }

        return connectedStatus;
    }
```